# Easy way to use large arrays in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Is there an easy way to do what the code below indicates?

- Using multiprocessing
- Use arbitrary large inputs, arrays etc.
- retrieve large outputs
- concatenate the outputs in the right order to get the  correct result

Right now the code blocks after the first join.

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
    
qout = Queue()
    
    
def do_stuff(large_input_multi_dim_arr,start_i,start_j):       
    //do stuff
    qout.put([end_pos,x,y,large_multi_dim_output_arr])
    
processes=[]
    
for i in range(0,10):
    processes+=[[]]
    processes[i] = 
    Process(target=do_stuff,
    args=(even_bigger_arr[i*large_num:i*large_num+large_num]
    ,i,j))
    processes[i].start()
    
for i in range(0,10):
    processes[i].join()
    
result=[]
while not qout.empty():
    result.append(qout.get())
```

Comment: "the code blocks after the first join" could be very likely because you're trying to join before retrieving the results from the queue. The queue's buffer may become full, and the worker will be stuck waiting to finish writing data while the main process is waiting for the child to exit (before reading the queue, and freeing any of that space.)

Comment: yes, but how can I empty the queue before the join?

Comment: `qout.get` will block until a result is available. there's no need to wait until the result is available using join. Don't rely on `while not qout.empty()` (it's not guaranteed to be reliable anyway), and instead calculate ahead of time how many results to expect and call `for _ in range(n_results): result.append(qout.get())`

Comment: This fixed it for me. For loop before join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code blocking is unrelated (see comment), but to answer the title question: I generally use shared memory to pass large numpy arrays between processes, as it requires much less processing overhead than a queue.

```py
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory

shape=[25]
dtype=float

def do_work(arr_in_shm: SharedMemory,
            worker_slice: slice,
            arr_out_shm: SharedMemory,
            param: float):
    arr_in = np.ndarray(shape, dtype, buffer=arr_in_shm.buf)
    arr_out = np.ndarray(shape, dtype, buffer=arr_out_shm.buf)

    #do some math on the input and store the result in the output array
    #no locking is needed if separate workers will never write to the same
    #   arr_out location (each having their own slice).
    arr_out[worker_slice] = arr_in[worker_slice] * param

    arr_in_shm.close()
    arr_out_shm.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    arr_in_shm = SharedMemory(create=True, size=(int(np.dtype(dtype).itemsize * np.prod(shape)))) #extra int() cast from numpy.int32 to python int
    arr_out_shm = SharedMemory(create=True, size=(int(np.dtype(dtype).itemsize * np.prod(shape))))

    arr_in = np.ndarray(shape, dtype, buffer=arr_in_shm.buf)
    arr_out = np.ndarray(shape, dtype, buffer=arr_out_shm.buf)


    #example data: 0,1,2, ... 24
    arr_in[:] = np.arange(arr_in.size)

    procs = []
    for i in range(0,25,5):
        p = Process(target=do_work, args=(arr_in_shm, slice(i, i+5), arr_out_shm, i**.5))
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)

    for p in procs:
        p.join()

    print(arr_out)

    #cleanup
    arr_in_shm.close()
    arr_in_shm.unlink()

    arr_out_shm.close()
    arr_out_shm.unlink()
```

Comment: Actually, doing it before the join and use a for loop instead solved the problem, but I count your answer as valid as well ;)
So your comment was the true solution for me.

Comment: Transferring data to and from worker processes (using queues) can become a large bottleneck if the size of the arrays grow large. This solution may be a good reference in case you run into this in the future.